# Joomla built website not working on Apache "Deprecated: Assigning the return value"

Tags: php, apache, joomla, deprecated

i have a stupid Joomla built website which i need to edit...just add one dynamic function i have all the source code... i imported the database.. & all all but it is not functioning there are stupid following errors

- Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\ihc\modules\mod_exmenu-j15\exmenu\exmenu.class.php on line 56
- Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\ihc.gov.pk\modules\mod_exmenu-j15\exmenu\exmenu.class.php on line 56
- Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\ihc.gov.pk\modules\mod_exmenu-j15\exmenu\exmenu.class.php on line 221

and there are a total of 27 of these.. what are these PHP warnings errors... or what what to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the PHP version you are using is 5.3
If you downgraded your PHP version to 5.2.x it will work perfectly
If you're on a live server contact your hosting company
If you're on local server and you are using WAMP you can download [version 5.2.9](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/wampserver/WampServer2-PHP529-2.exe?download) and install it then change the current active version to the new one.

Answer (score 1):

i believe this is to do with PHP4's limited OOP capabilities and how you would have to pass values by reference manually (Foo(&$foo)); whereas in PHP5 this is done automatically.

If you're using PHP5, which is probably quite likely, you'll need to go through the code and remove any reference within it manually.

Comment: or you could set display errors to none and you shouldn't recive the message

Comment: well when people grow up (become professionals), they stop hiding under the bed